# Bitbucket server REST API via Python

Tags: python, bitbucket-server, stashy

I would like to use the REST API service of Bitbucket server in Python. Till now I tried the python module called stashy, but I could not even connect. The snippet

```
import stashy
stash = stashy.connect("http://localhost:7990/stash", "<user>", "<pass>")
stash.admin.groups.list()
```

raises the exception

```
stashy.errors.GenericException: Unknown error: 503(Service Unavailable)
```

By simply running a GET request via curl

```
curl -u <user>:<pass> http://127.0.0.1:7990/stash
```

I get a page, which shows I am logged in.

My environment:

Python:
2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]

Bitbucket:
Atlassian Bitbucket v5.13.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The example connection URL of `"http://localhost:7990/stash"` in the stashy docs is just an example.  If you want to connect to a "real" instance of Bitbucket Server, you need to change that URL accordingly.

Just visit your Bitbucket Server site in a web browser and copy the first part of the URL.  It's probably something like `https://bitbucket.mycompany.com`, and use the same username and password as you'd use via your web browser.

`stash = stashy.connect("https://bitbucket.mycompany.com", "myusername", "mypassword")`